# How to create a list with perticular strings from another list in python using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a List Class "state_wise_data".

List is

```
[
array(['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 5201, 5050, 62, 89,'12-04-2021 22.58'], dtype=object), array(['Andhra Pradesh', 928664, 898238, 7311, 23115, '12-04-2021 20.49'], dtype=object), 
....
]
```

I pulled the first value out of it.

```
for value in state_wise_data:
     print(value[0])
```

Output

```
Andaman and Nicobar Islands
Andhra Pradesh
.
.
```

Now I want to create a list in this perticular format

```
form.country.choices = [('Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'), (' Andhra Pradesh', ' Andhra Pradesh'),.....('n', 'n')]
```

---

I tried List comprehension....

For eg :

```
res = [(n, n) for n in map(str, range(1,10))]
```

Which will yield

```
[('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ..., ('10', '10')]
```

Similarly, Can I get

```
[('Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'), (' Andhra Pradesh', ' Andhra Pradesh'),.....('n', 'n')]
```

Please Help ?

Comment: Your data is not properly organized.  If this were a single 2D numpy array, you could use slice notation.  But as a plain list of numpy objects, you'll have to use `[(n[0],n[0]) for n in state_wise_data]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be as simple as ABC.

```
lists = [('nothing','your'),('everything','their'),('something','our')]

[(item[0],item[0]) for item in lists]
```

To make it even quicker, you can use numpy and slice the numpy array straight away